# Reusing PHPMailer to send out a second email?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am working on an ordering system, which will need to send the customer, distributor and the website owner an email.

The owner and distributor can get the same email (order details etc), but the customer needs one with a slightly different body to incorporate a thank you message.

Currently I have this:

```
require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
//$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "";
$mail->Password = "";
$mail->SetFrom("");
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Online Shop - New Order - " . $orderNumber;
$mail->Body = "A new order has been placed with Online Shop. Please find the delivery details below: <br><br> " . $orderDetails;
$mail->AddAddress($distributerEmail); //Distributor email address
$mail->AddAddress($ownerEmail); //Owner email address
if($mail->Send()){  }else{ $error = "Error sending message! <br/>"; }
```

How can I reuse the $mail component, to send another email without having to define the server details as well? I

Comment: Would the best way be to turn this into a function?

Comment: The accepted answer is ok, though it looks like you've used an old example to base your code on (and perhaps are running an old version of PHPMailer). What you're doing is fairly similar to [the mailing list example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) bundled with PHPMailer.

Comment: @Synchro I'm using the example code provided here: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial

Comment: @Synchro using 5.2.7

Comment: Yep, that's site's years out of date and 5.2.7 is from September 2013 - things have moved on since then. Look [on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), read the README and other docs in the docs and example folders and also the github wiki.

Comment: If I drop in the latest version, would my code have to change?

Comment: Just load the autoloader instead of the class file, as per the readme. There are other differences but they don't matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
//$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "";
$mail->Password = "";
$mail->SetFrom("");
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Online Shop - New Order - " . $orderNumber;
$mail->Body = "A new order has been placed with Online Shop. Please find the delivery details below: <br><br> " . $orderDetails;
$mail->AddAddress($distributerEmail); //Distributor email address
$mail->AddAddress($ownerEmail); //Owner email address
if($mail->Send()){  }else{ $error = "Error sending message! <br/>"; }

// We delete the addresses of distributer and owner.
$mail->ClearAddresses();

$mail->AddAddress($customerEmail);
$mail->Body = "new body";

if($mail->Send()){  }else{ $error = "Error sending message! <br/>"; }
```

Comment: I found this: `$mail->ClearAllRecipients();` Is it the same thing?

Comment: In your case yes. `ClearAllRecipientes();` clears `TO`,  `BCC` and `CC`. `ClearAddresses()` only clears `TO`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Extract the Mailer creation to a function

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

function createMailer(): PHPMailer
{
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->isSMTP();
    $mailer->Host = getenv('mail.host');
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mailer->Username = getenv('mail.username');
    $mailer->Password = getenv('mail.password');
    $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mailer->Port = 587;
    $mailer->setFrom(getenv('mail.from.address'), getenv('mail.from.name'));
    $mailer->isHTML();
    $mailer->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;

    return $mailer;
}
```

- Support for the return type declaration `: PHPMailer` that I'm using down there [was added in PHP 7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) - if you use an older PHP version just remove it.
- I have the `"phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.9"` dependency is in my `composer.json`.
- I'm reading some values here from environment variables - you could hardcode them though

#### Send multiple mails like this

```php
$mailer = createMailer();

// 1st mail
$mailer->clearAddresses();
$mailer->addAddress('hello@example.com');
$mailer->Subject = 'Your Subject';
$mailer->Body = 'Hello name,<br><br>your order has been received.';
if ($mailer->send()) {
    echo '1st mail sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'Failed to send 1st mail.';
}

// 2nd mail
$mailer->clearAddresses();
$mailer->addAddress('hello2@example.com');
$mailer->Subject = 'Your Subject';
$mailer->Body = 'Hello name,<br><br>your order has been received.';
if ($mailer->send()) {
    echo '2nd mail sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'Failed to send 2nd mail.';
}
```

- I only clear the receivers' addresses before sending another mail here... *but*:

  - if you used CC or BCC fields in a previous mail (via `->addCC()` or `->addBCC()`), you would have to `->ClearAllRecipients()` instead of `->clearAddresses()`
  - if you used attachments (via `->addAttachment()`), that you don't want the next mail to have as well, you'd have to call `->clearAttachments()` before sending another mail

If you send mails in a lot of places, consider extracting the code that is still duplicate to another function like `sendMail($recipient, $subject, $body)`: then you'll send mails with a one-liner.

#### Sources

- [Official GitHub documentation of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
- [Source Code of PHPMailer 6.9.1](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/039de174cd9c17a8389754d3b877a2ed22743e18/src/PHPMailer.php#L4030-L4093)